# MSI Uninstall issue: Error 1001 -> The saved State dictionary contains inconsistent data and might have been corrupted

Tags: c#, windows-services, windows-installer, installation, uninstallation

I need to create a few Windows Services and obviously I would like to package them in a nice installer.

Since I was unfamiliar with Service creation/installation I basically used code from the following example:

[Advanced Service Installation](http://thecurlybrace.blogspot.com/2010/12/advanced-c-windows-service-installation.html)

I did not change ProjectInstaller or InstallActions and basically just plugged my own services (File monitoring/conversion).

Building and compiling the code works A-OK:

1. The Installer works, the services are installed (but NOT started as might be expected)
2. My Services themselves all work
3. The Uninstall FAILS, stating the error from the title

**What is very strange:**

If, after the failed uninstall, I run "Repair" and subsequently manually remove *.Installstate from the installation folder, the uninstaller magically works.

This is driving me nuts.

I guess I could just document this quirk for the potential users of my service but I don't like not knowing what is really going on.

Debugging this sort of thing is really hard (wouldn't even know how) and documentation is very scarce (non-existing even).

Anybody with some tips?

Answer (score 8):

**I solved this problem by doing this:**

- Go to the folder installation
- Edit the file xxxxxxx.InstallState with notepad or an XML editor (where xxxxx is the name of your service)
- Go to `ArrayOfKeyValueOfanyTypeanyType` node and then to `Keys` node
- Delete `anyType` child
- Go to the Values node and delete all `anyType` child
- Save the file and try to uninstall

**This works for me. regards**

Comment: highly appreciated this much detailed answer:P

Comment: This looks like something that could work, but I have no idea where to look for the `.installState` file. It's nowhere to be foud, even for other packages. Not present in the VS project, not in the folder with installed program. And can't google it so far.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same problem and I've managed to fix it by adding proper conditions to Custom Actions. In my case I've added **Not Installed** to my Windows Service Installer at the Install and Uninstall phase. There were no errors after that.
Hope this will help! Find more information on this issues [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformssetup/thread/b2d1bd22-8499-454e-9cec-1e42c03e2557/#044596f3-62a0-4c51-9b59-d1db5a5956af).

Answer (score 1):

I Know this is an old post but I fixed my problem by calling the Installer class base prior to performing my custom actions, I accidentally added my code by the base calls first.

Answer (score 1):

Go to control panel and first repair your setup. After the successful repair you will be able to uninstall.

Comment: Your comment helped me out a lot though.  Thanks! +1

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where a Windows Installer Package (.msi) was not uninstalling as expected. The workaround for me was to use the command line to uninstall using InstallUtil.exe. Then, reinstall the service using InstallUtil.exe. After, I was finally able to use an old msi to uninstall. After I uninstalled using the old MSI, I was able to use a NEW msi to install and everything worked as desired.