# Windows service error: the savedState dictionary does not contain the expected values and might have been corrupted

Tags: c#, windows-services, windows-installer

I'm trying to create multiple services using one EXE file.

I've added a installer class:

```
[RunInstaller(true)]
public partial class POCInstall : System.Configuration.Install.Installer
{
    private ServiceProcessInstaller m_ServiceProcess;
    private ServiceInstaller m_ServiceInstaller;
    public POCInstall()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        m_ServiceProcess = new ServiceProcessInstaller();
        m_ServiceProcess.Account = ServiceAccount.NetworkService;
        m_ServiceProcess.Username = null;
        m_ServiceProcess.Password = null;

        m_ServiceInstaller = new ServiceInstaller();
        m_ServiceInstaller.BeforeInstall += new InstallEventHandler(onBeforeInstall);
        m_ServiceInstaller.BeforeUninstall += new InstallEventHandler(onBeforeUninstall);
        m_ServiceInstaller.BeforeRollback += new InstallEventHandler(onBeforRollback);
        m_ServiceInstaller.ServiceName = "POCService";
        this.Installers.Add(m_ServiceProcess);
        this.Installers.Add(m_ServiceInstaller);
    }

    private void onBeforRollback(object sender, InstallEventArgs e)
    {
        string serviceName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServiceName"];
        string serviceDsiaply = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServiceDsiaply"];
        m_ServiceInstaller.ServiceName = serviceName;
        m_ServiceInstaller.DisplayName = serviceDsiaply;
    }

    private void onBeforeUninstall(object sender, InstallEventArgs e)
    {
        string serviceName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServiceName"];
        string serviceDsiaply = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServiceDsiaply"];
        m_ServiceInstaller.ServiceName = serviceName;
        m_ServiceInstaller.DisplayName = serviceDsiaply;
    }

    private void onBeforeInstall(object sender, InstallEventArgs e)
    {
        string serviceName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServiceName"];
        string serviceDsiaply = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServiceDsiaply"];
        m_ServiceInstaller.ServiceName = serviceName;
        m_ServiceInstaller.DisplayName = serviceDsiaply;
    }

}
```

As you can see, I get the service name and parameter from the app config file:

```
 <add key="ServiceName" value="POCService1"/>
 <add key="ServiceDsiaply" value="POC Service 1"/>
```

The service class is empty and only have empty onStart and OnStop methods.

```
public partial class POCService : ServiceBase
{
    public POCService()
    {
        this.ServiceName = "POCService";
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
    }
}
```

When I do the install using command line, `%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\InstallUtil.exe ServicePOC.exe`

I get the error:

`An exception occurred during the Rollback phase of the System.ServiceProcess.ServiceInstaller installer.
System.ArgumentException: The savedState dictionary does not contain the expected values and might have been corrupted.`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MSI Uninstall issue: Error 1001 -> The saved State dictionary contains inconsistent data and might have been corrupted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6618634/msi-uninstall-issue-error-1001-the-saved-state-dictionary-contains-inconsist)

Answer (score 1):

Implement an empty `public override void Commit(IDictionary savedState)` method.

Comment: This initially seemed to work for me but then on trying to uninstall the next next version (with the empty method in) I had the same problem again.

Comment: For info editing the installState file seems to have worked for me - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6618634/msi-uninstall-issue-error-1001-the-saved-state-dictionary-contains-inconsist/36902187#36902187