# Error while trying to unninstall a Windows service

Tags: c#, service

I successfully created a Windows service with C#. Sometimes, while trying to uninstall the service, an exception is thrown:

```
Message - 
   The savedState dictionary contains inconsistent data and might have been corrupted    
Type - 
   ArgumentException
Source - 
   System.Configuration.Install
TargetSite - 
   Void Uninstall(System.Collections.IDictionary)
StackTrace - 
   at System.Configuration.Install.Installer.Uninstall(IDictionary savedState)
   at System.Configuration.Install.Installer.Uninstall(IDictionary savedState)
```

The only way to uninstall that service is rebooting the system and trying again.

Comment: Check out this question: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6618634/msi-uninstall-issue-error-1001-the-saved-state-dictionary-contains-inconsist)

Comment: I don't use a MSI installer. So, I guess it isn't the same problem.